# PMD: Is there a way for rule writer to get the package name of the current node?

Tags: java, pmd

Well I have the Node, and I can get what class Name it in, but I cannot get package of this class.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

BTW: I'm talking about PMD, so people who don't know what PMD be, don't answer about how a java object can get its package again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `this.getClass().getName()` to get packageName.className and use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get only class name. If ou want full name use `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()` to get the full class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have java.lang.Class then you can call .getPackage().getName() on it to get its package name.

```
package stackoverflow;
public class Clazz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String packageName = Clazz.class.getPackage().getName();
        System.out.println("packageName = " + packageName);
    }
}
```